# RapidJSON alternative

Tags: c++, json

I'm looking for an alternative to RapidJSON library.

Specs:

- library
- written in C++ (to be integrated with C++ code)
- opensource
- free for commercial usage
- bidirectional conversion (serialization and deserialization to/from JSON)
- permit access to raw representation of DOM
- perhaps, also be extensible

Comment: Yes. Updated post.

Comment: might check the source code behind PHP's `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there seem to be only 4 alternatives:

- https://github.com/nlohmann/json
- https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp
- https://github.com/dropbox/json11
- https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto